# Kernel - Linux - Where does the kernel talks to the cpu?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

#### Context:

Linux 64.
Intel Core 2 duo.

#### Question:

Where does the Linux kernel "communicate" with the cpu ?
I read the source code for scheduler but could not understand **how** they communicate and how the kernel tells the cpu that something need to be processed.

I understand that there are run queues, but isn't there something that enables the kernel to interrupt the cpu via the bus ?

### Update

It expands my initial questions a bit : How can we tell the cpu **where** the task queues are ?

Because the cpu has to poll something, and i guess we tell it at some point. Missed that point in the kernel code.

Comment: Kernel is a program that CPU is running. That's all. It's a bunch of commands in the memory which is fetched and executed by CPU.

Comment: Yes but how exactly are the queues tied to the cpu ? Are there some kind of interrupts ? is the cpu busywaiting the scheduler's queues ?

Comment: CPU is selcting the prcoesses to run as per the scheduler policies and just running them one after another..When there is interrupt it runs interrupt service routine.. and so on

Comment: Ok so, in THEORY, if there are nothing to do it is busy waiting the queues, right ?

Comment: @Larry What queues are you talking about?

Comment: If there is absolutely nothing to do.. the CPU cores could be halted.. atleast that is what cpu governors do.

Comment: Are you asking about `pm_idle()`? This has already been asked before - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749479/linux-kernel-idle-loop

Comment: @sashoalm: the task queues. Are there some enforced rules that acknowledge the cpu that "it is there you have to look for the list of work to be processed"?

Comment: @Larry Acknowledge the CPU? What do you mean by that? The CPU is acknowledged by the task queues? Or what? Check the dictionary for what acknowledge means, you need to speak English well enough to at least be understood. Acknowledge doesn't mean to inform or to tell.

Comment: @sashoalm : this is exactly the point i don't understand ! Is it the cpu that spins the queues or the kernel that "tells" the cpu that there is some things to do ?

Comment: The CPU is running the kernel, so there is no distinction between those two scenarios.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: ok so how the cpu knows there is some work to do ? at some point, it has to know where to look, right ? Are there any enforced conventions ?

Comment: This question as written is WAY too broad. Please specify an architecture and preferably a single type of CPU e.g. core i5 etc. As this question is written there is no single good answer as it is very hardware dependent.

Comment: @Larry The CPU does not know about the scheduler or task queues, those are concepts implemented by the kernel. The CPU just runs instructions. (That's true today, the initial version of linux 2 decades ago did use cpu task switching that was built into the i386 CPUs.)

Comment: There is a queue strcture defined somewhere like `struct list_head queue` and `schedule()` knows that it has to take the task from there

Comment: @Larry, what do you mean "knows"? The CPU doesn't know anything; all the scheduling logic lives in the software. If you're asking how that software gets run, then we need to talk about timer interrupts.

Comment: @Larry The problem here is that you don't understand what you're talking about. The solution is to go and read a book on the topic. Seriously. I doubt we can give you any better advice. Kernel programming is not a simple thing, and this is not the place to teach it to you.

Comment: @sashoalm : thanks. Any reading advice ?

Comment: if I understand what you're looking for I would start [here](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/kernel/cpu/common.c) which is the file where the kernel interacts with the Global Descriptor Table which controls memory and tasks

Comment: @Larry [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Third-Edition/dp/0596005652) has a great chapter on how the Linux scheduler works.

Comment: @Larry Just type "kernel programming tutorial" in Google ;)

Comment: i don't use google but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will try to write a simplified explanation of how it works, tell me if anything is unclear.

A CPU only do one thing : execute instructions. It will start at a predefined address, and execute. That's all. Sometime you can have an interrupt, that will temporarily make the CPU jump to another instruction.

A kernel is a program (=a sequence of instructions) that will make it easy to execute other programs. The kernel will do his business to setup what it needs. This often include building a list of process to run. The definition of "process" is totally up to the kernel because, as you know, the CPU only do one thing.

Now, when the kernel runs (being executed by the CPU), it might decide that one process needs to be executed. To do so, the kernel will simply jump to the process program. How it is done doesn't matter, but in most OSes, the kernel will map a periodic interrupt (the CPU will periodically jump) to a function that decide which process to execute and jump to it. It isn't required, but it is convenient because programs will be forcefully "interrupted" periodically so others can also be executed.

To sum up, the CPU doesn't "know" anything. The kernel runs, and will jump to other process code to make them run. Only the kernel "knows".

Comment: Rings the bell ! The kernel jumps to the address. This is what i missed ! I will try to find a clue on how it does that in the kernel source. i guess I will meet the tss, the GDT and family there :)

Comment: @Larry The transition (jump) from kernel to process usually comes with a context switch. i.e the previous process context is saved and the next process context is loaded.

Comment: Thanks you so much ElderBug, I am reading a lot on the subject now and start to grab how things work. You understood where I was failing : the big picture. Thanks to your help.

Comment: @Larry Glad to help. If you didn't already come across it, the [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) is really interesting for general OS mechanisms. If you scroll down a bit on the main page, at the 'Design Considerations' section, you have some points about scheduling.

Comment: This is exactly what i needed as a starter. Thanks again.

Comment: @Larry if you mean the task switching segment by "tss", you won't see that - it was used by the initial linux versions on x86 CPUs to do hardware assisted task switching, but it's an obsolete feature and unused by pretty much all operating systems now.

Comment: @nos: i was talking about the structure to do software switching. The kernel still needs one to proceed the switch, am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

The Linux kernel is a program. It doesn't "talk" to the CPU as such; the CPU has a special register, the [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) (PC), which points to the current execution of the kernel which the CPU is processing.

The kernel itself contains many services. One of them manages the task queues. Each entry in the task queue contains information about the task. One such information is the CPU core on which the task is running. When the kernel decides that the service should do some work, it will call it's functions. The functions are made up from [instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) which the CPU interprets. Most of them change the state of the CPU (like advancing the PC, changing register values, setting flags, enabling/disabling CPU cores, ...).

This means the CPU isn't polling anything. Depending on the scheduler, different strategies are used to process the task queue. The most simple one is timer based: The kernel install a timer interrupt (i.e. it writes the address of an interrupt handler somewhere plus it configured the timer to cause an interrupt every few milliseconds).

The handler then looks at the task queue and decides what to do, depending on its strategy.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I need to read more about that. i don't get the whole picture "I guess". :)